# Is there an optimized "normalized difference" function in the scipy/pandas/theano/etc ecosystem?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gis, theano

Right now I've got a variety of geographic features that I compute along the following lines:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
df['x'] = ...
df['y'] = ...
...
x = theano.tensor.dvector()
y = theano.tensor.dvector()
z = (x - y) / (x + y)
df['z'] = theano.function([x, y], z)(df['x'], df['y'])
```

My intuition tells me that this kind of "normalized difference" would be a very common operation, and that there may well be something already out there that handles this more cleanly and/or efficiently.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

`df['z'] = (df['x'] - df['y']) / (df['x'] + df['y'])` should be very efficient. Your `theano` way is probably pretty fast too. Time it to find out what's fastest with your data.

To make it clean, you can rewrite:

```
def normalized_difference(a, b):
    return (x-y) / (x+y)
df['z'] = normalized_difference(df['x'], df['y'])
test = normalized_difference(11.0, 9.0) # 0.1
```

Or use `norm_diff = theano.function([x, y], z)` which you can reuse like `norm_diff(df['x'], df['y'])`, as many times as you like.